# Selection formula for capturing previous month data only in lotus notes

Tags: lotus-notes

what selection formula we have to used for capturing previous month data only in a view in lotus notes 7.0 version

Answer (score 2):

Please note that view selection formulas using variable times (@Now, @Today) are hell on server performance, since every time the view is accessed it needs to check when "now" is. In Notes and Domino 7, you would be far better off to use a hard-coded date range and a scheduled agent to change the view selection formula on a monthly or daily basis (depending on whether you mean "last month" or "between this date last month and today").

Please see the [Performance Basics for Lotus Notes Developers](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/lotus/documentation/d-ls-notesperformance/) whitepaper for more information.

Comment: I echo Stan's answer, do not use a viwe for this, its very bad design and will kill the application and server performance as the application grows bigger.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to compare the date field in your documents to @Today minus one month, and select all documents with a date greater than or equal to that calculated date.

Use the @Adjust formula to calculate the current date minus one month:

```
SELECT @Adjust(@Today, 0;-1;0;0;0;0) >= YOURDATEFIELD
```

Comment: Put this code into a scheduled agent and run it once a day at 6:00am, if document date passes the test then set a field on the documents so they appear in a view (e.g. if field lastMonth = "Yes")